# Anchor: Initialize token mint with metadata and extension transfer fee

Tags: anchor, spl-token, mint, invoke

I would like to initialize in my Anchor program a new token to mint with extension transfer fee and metadata. It keeps return error InvalidAccountData when invoke initialize_transfer_fee_config, i think there is something wrong with this part

let acc = vec![
ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
];

My code:

```
 pub fn initialize_token_mint(ctx: Context<InitializeMint>, params: InitTokenParams) -> Result<()> {

    msg!("Start set fee for token");
    let seeds = &["mint".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
    let signer = [&seeds[..]];

    let acc = vec![
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
    ];

    let ix = initialize_transfer_fee_config(
        &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(), // SPL Token program ID
        &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),          // Mint account
        Some(&ctx.accounts.user.key()),
        Some(&ctx.accounts.user.key()),
        params.transfer_fee_basis_points, // Basis points for the transfer fee
        params.maximum_fee,// Maximum fee
    ).unwrap();

    invoke(
        &ix,
        acc.as_slice(),
    )?;
    msg!("Set init transfer fee successfully");

    let account_init_mint_ix = vec![
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    ];

    invoke(
        &initialize_mint(
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            Some(&ctx.accounts.mint.key()),
            params.decimals,
        )?,
        account_init_mint_ix.as_slice(),
    )?;
    msg!("Set init mint fee successfully");

    let account_fee_ix = vec![
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
    ];

    invoke(
        &set_transfer_fee(
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(), // SPL Token program ID
            &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),          // Mint account
            &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            &[&ctx.accounts.user.key()],
            params.transfer_fee_basis_points, // Basis points for the transfer fee
            params.maximum_fee,// Maximum fee
        ).unwrap(),
        account_fee_ix.as_slice(),
    )?;
    msg!("Set fee fee successfully");

    let account_info = vec![
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    ];

    invoke_signed(
        &mpl_instruction::create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.user.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            params.name,
            params.symbol,
            params.uri,
            None,
            0,
            true,
            true,
            None,
            None,
            None,
        ),
        account_info.as_slice(),
        &signer,
    )?;

    msg!("Token metadata created successfully.");

    Ok(())
}
```

```
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    #[instruction(
      params: InitTokenParams
    )]
    pub struct InitializeMint<'info> {
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = user,
    space = 8 + 8,
    seeds = ["mint22".as_bytes()],
    bump
    )]
    pub mint: AccountInfo<'info, >,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK:
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: account constraint checked in account trait
    #[account(address = MetadataID)]
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(
params: InitTokenParams
)]
pub struct InitializeMint<'info> {
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = user,
    space = 8 + 8,
    seeds = ["mint22".as_bytes()],
    bump
    )]
    pub mint: AccountInfo<'info, >,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK:
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: account constraint checked in account trait
    #[account(address = MetadataID)]
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Then I run a script at client side TS, it showed log error:

```
 logs: [
    'Program DczPycuxn6dM7nRpojKgZcduMWHiXdaEPvCWCqLED97h invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeTokenMint',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: Start set fee for token',
    'Program log: Start signed 1',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 1310 of 188290 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: invalid account data for instruction',
    'Program DczPycuxn6dM7nRpojKgZcduMWHiXdaEPvCWCqLED97h consumed 13020 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program DczPycuxn6dM7nRpojKgZcduMWHiXdaEPvCWCqLED97h failed: invalid account data for instruction'
  ],
```

Please help me find the problem. Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your mint is only defined as having `8 + 8` bytes, which is not enough for the transfer fee extension.

If you want your mint to have the extension, you'll need at least 278 bytes allocated:

- 165 for the base account
- 1 for the account type
- 2 for the extension type
- 2 for the extension length
- 108 for the extension

You may want to start with an example that creates a mint with the transfer fee extension. You can find all the Rust tests at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022-test/tests/transfer_fee.rs and some JS examples at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/examples/transferFee.ts

Comment: I will try again, thanks for your answer